# Opção padrão "Outras..." em um datalist, tem como remover?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Bom dia!

```
<datalist id="datalist">
     <option value="08:00"></option>
     <option value="08:30"></option> 
     <option value="09:00"></option> 
</datalist>

<input list="datalist" class="form-control" type="time">
```

Seguindo esse código tem ocorrido o que eu desejo exceto por uma coisa, ele adiciona uma opção por padrão "Outras..." e eu não quero que ele fique ai... E simplesmente não consigo tirar, já tentei criar essa opção com um id e tentar remover com javascript, mas não consegui por nada... Alguém sabe se da pra tirar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você precisa de uma lista não opcional, por que não usar um `<select>` então?

Comment: Porque estou manipulando muito essa lista com javascript e achei bem mais facil fazer isso com datalist, mas caso não tenha como tirar essa opção "Outras.." terei que refazer uma parte do meu código pra ser com um select mesmo.

Comment: Pelo que vejo, tanto o `input[type=time]` quanto o `datalist`, o comportamento vai variar de browser pra browser. Então talvez a solução seja usar o bom e velho `select`.

Comment: Estou achando isso também, obrigado pela ajuda!